# VB2005 crash in Debug Mode 'Method not found'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, debugging, dll

I have an old DLL that works fine.
This DLL is called in a project.

I updated the DLL with a new function.
In the project I call the DLL's new function.
The project's IDE show me the new function.
At run time all works good.

In debug mode the project crashes with a message  'method not found'.
I tried to delete BIN end OBJ directory... but nothing worked.

Anyone can help me ?
Thanks

Comment: It is pretty obvious that at runtime it is still using the old DLL.  We can't tell you why, you'll have to figure this out yourself.  First useful tool is the debugger, use Debug > Windows > Modules and locate the DLL in the list.  Tells you where it found the DLL.  Second one is Fuslogvw.exe, log all the binds and look at the trace afterwards to see how it probed for the DLL.

Comment: In runtime mode use new dll and new function. I'm sure about it.
 I'd seen in  Debug > Windows > Modules   and in the list the are the right DLL version

Comment: Do you have tried clear your solution and delete the .suo file? Please clear and rebuild your solution. In addition, please check the dll path in your project References (select the dll and press F4 to open the Properties window) to make sure that path is correct.